# How to write a for loop program that finds the sum of all odd numbers in a range, but does not use the if function

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I need to write a code that asks for user input 'num' of any number and calculates the sum of all odd numbers in the range of 1 to num. I can't seem to figure out how to write this code, because we had a similar question about adding the even numbers in a range that I was able to figure out.

I've also added the lines of code that I've written already for any critiques of what I may have done right/wrong. Would greatly appreciate any help with this :)

```
total = 0

for i in range(0, num + 1, 1):
    total = total + i
return total
```

Answer (score 6):

```
total = sum(range(1, num + 1, 2))
```

if you really need a for loop:

```
total = 0
for i in range(1, num+1, 2):
    total += i
```

and to make it more exotic, you can consider the property that `i%2==1` only for odd numbers and `i%2==0` for even numbers (caution: you make your code unreadable)

```
total = 0
for i in range(1, num+1):
    total += i * (i % 2)
```

You can invent a lot more ways to solve this problem by exploiting the even-odd properties, such as:

- `(-1)^i` is 1 or -1
- `i & 0x1` is 0 or 1
- `abs(((1j)**i).real)` is 0 or 1

and so on

Comment: I especially love the complex number one. +1

Answer (score 3):

The range function has three parameters: start, stop, and step.

For instance: `for i in range(1, 100, 2)` will loop from 1-99 on odd numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution

You can use math formula

```
#sum of odd numbers till n
def n_odd_sum(n):
    return ((n+1)//2)**2
print(n_odd_sum(1))
print(n_odd_sum(2))
print(n_odd_sum(3))
print(n_odd_sum(4))
print(n_odd_sum(5))
```

```
1
1
4
4
9
```

Answer (score 1):

Using filter:

```
start_num = 42
end_num = 500
step = 7
sum([*filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 1, [*range(start_num, end_num+1, step)])])
```

Answer (score 1):

#### You can use the math formula *(works every time)*:

```
num = int(input("Input an odd number: "))
total = (1+num)**2//4
print(total)
```

#### Output:

```
Input an odd number: 19
100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
total = 0

num = int(input())
for i in range(num+1):
    if i%2 == 1:
        total += i

print (total)
```

The `%` operator returns the remainder, in this case, the remainder when you divide n/2. If that is 1, it means your number is odd, you can add that to your total.

You can of course do it in 1 line with python, but this might be easier to understand.

Comment: One of the conditions is that the if statement can't be used

Comment: hi, i was able to figure out how to do the question using an if function, but one of the conditions of the assignment is to print the solution without using an if function in the code

Comment: You can change the range to `(1, num+1, 2)` then it will loop through only odd numbers.